# Hide custom field value

Tags: plugins, child-theme

On wordpress, I want to hide custom field values only with a button called "For registered members" with a specific hyperlink called "/membership".

Here's the demo listing link: https://main.mylistingtheme.com/listing/bmw-316-d-facelift/

And here's the sample image (what I want): https://prnt.sc/zg40yh

Can you please share the code for me just for one custom field which I can use in the child theme's functions.php file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the registered users are all within the WP user table then you can do something like this

```
<?php 
 if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
  /// link to membership section
 } else {
  /// link to signup page?
 }
?>
```

This will check the current status of the user and see if they are logged in or not.

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: I want to hide the value of the custom fields as per choice. Can you show me any sample code? I want exactly as this picture: https://prnt.sc/zg40yh

Comment: Currently, all custom field values are visible. I want a code that will make the custom fields look like as this link: https://prnt.sc/zg40yh